# set selected field when define with 'type' => 'select' in magento

Tags: magento

I have a custom module where I create a form.
One field is a dropdown with values from a flat file.

```
    $fields =  array(
        'type_of_service' => array('display' => 'Tip serviciu',
            'required' => true,
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => $serviceTypeOptions,
```

How can I set one value to be selected ?

EDIT:

if I use something like this in *_prepareForm()*

```
        $fieldset->addField('select', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('tracking')->__('Select'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'title',
            'value'  => '3',
            'values' => array('-1'=>'Please Select..','1' => 'Option1','2' => 'Option2', '3' => 'Option3'),
        )),
```

preselected will be 3.
But I generate my fields previously, and assign those to form with

*$formFields = $this->getFormFields();*

The problem is that I can't use the addField method, I need to have them created within my function.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
'required'  => true,
'value'     => '2',
'values'    => array(
                  array('1' => 'Option 1','2' => 'Option 2'),
...
```

which will select `Option 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
'required'  => true,
'value'     => 2,
'values'    => array(
                  array('label' => 'Option 2', value => 2),
                  array('label' => 'Option 1', value => 1)
               )
```

A full example can be like below

```
    $fieldset->addField(
        'target_type', 
        'select',
        array(
            'label' => $this->__("Target Type"),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => 'true',
            'name' => 'target_type',
            'note' => $this->__("Target Type"),
            'value' => 2,
            'values' => array(
                array(
                    'value' => 2,
                    'label' => 'Option 2'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

**NOTE :** If you want to know about any of the Varien_Data_Form_Elements, you can directly do an inspection of Varien library `/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Select.php` in your case.